# Is it I/O manipulators that provide the functionality of << and >>?

Tags: c++

I have read about [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) and have thereof been a little confused.It is stated that it is because of these manipulators that we are able to control streams using << and >>. I am not quite sure why, but I have always thought that is was objects, such as std::cout, that controlled the functionality of operators, such as <<.

How is it even possible that functions, since I/O manipulators allegedly are functions, can overload/define operators? :/

Being specific, they state the following for manipulators taking arguments:

> These manipulators define their own operator<< or operator>> which
>   perform the requested manipulation.

If this is true - that it is not the objects (the classes that they belong to), but these helper functions that control the operators << and >> - how it is known what to do in the following statement?

```
std::cout << "static constructor\n";
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes? I have tried my best to elaborate on my confusion. Maybe the question is stupid, as I said, I am rather certain that I have misunderstood something, but that is exactly why I have reached out to you guys.

Comment: I didn't vote but it sounds like you have not really done any research into how overloaded operators work at all. I would recommend reading through [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard input and output stream classes (`std::basic_istream` and `std::basic_ostream`) overload member and non-member `operator>>()` and `operator<<()` functions. Those are the functions that perform the actual I/O. Manipulators are functions like `std::endl`, `std::left`, `std::right`, `std::boolalpha`, etc. They merely *complement* the functionality provided by the I/O operator functions. They allow us to control certain properties of the I/O operation like floating point representation, field width, fill characters, and so on.

In regards to the example you provided:

```
std::cout << "static constructor\n";
```

This calls the non-member function `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const char*);` which does the actual output of the string.

A manipulator can be defined like this:

```
std::ostream& print_1_to_10( std::ostream& os ) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    os << to_string(i);
  }
}
```

The standard stream classes have member overloads of `operator>>()` and `operator<<()` which take as an argument a pointer to a function with the above signature. Basically it goes like:

```
std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream&(*pf)(std::ostream&)) {
  pf(*this);
  return *this;
}
```

This allows us to do:

```
std::cout << print_1_to_10;
```

which is what allows manipulators to work.

So in summary, manipulators are simply helper functions that facilitate certain kinds of operations.

---

There is also the case where you might want something that resembles a manipulator, but in addition you want to pass arguments to this manipulator (i.e `std::cout << print_1_to(10)`). In that case it is customary to create a class that contains an overloaded `operator<<()` or `operator>>()` depending on what you want to do.

```
struct print_1_to {
  int n;
  print_1_to(int n) : n(n) {}
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, print_1_to const& p) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= p.n; i++) {
      os << to_string(i);
    }
    return os;
  }
};
```

Comment: That's a good answer but it's not quite complete. It is how `std::endl` works, but the quoted text in the question applies to "manipulators taking arguments", which use a slightly different mechanism.

Comment: Thank you!! But if it is said that manipulators are functions, how come the struct print_1_to is considered a manipulators? I know that there is a contructor, but it is still an instantiation of a struct.

Comment: @sdsadasdasd It's not a manipulator. It's a class that acts like a manipulator.

Comment: @0x499602D2 oh okay! But based on what you said, cppreference's statement "Manipulators are helper functions that make it possible to control input/output streams using operator<< or operator>>." just seems to totally wrong. Isn't that right?

Comment: Also, they state "The manipulators that are invoked with arguments (e.g. std::cout << std::setw(10);) are implemented as functions returning objects of unspecified type. These manipulators define their own operator << or operator >> which perform the requested manipulation." - if "These manipulators define their own operator << or operator >> which perform the requested manipulation", aren't they classes that act like a manipulator as the one you wrote in your answer? Otherwise, they would not be able to define their own versions, correct? Thanks! I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @noflow Yes, that is correct. They are classes that act as manipulators. A manipulator is a function with the signature `basic_istream<cT, traits>& (basic_stream<cT, traits>&)` or `basic_ostream<cT, traits>& (basic_ostream<cT, traits>&)` (which basically means "a function that takes an input stream and returns the given input stream or a function that takes an output stream and returns the given output stream")

Answer (score 0):

The text you quote is poor wording.

The standard headers define both the manipulator, and a free-function overloaded operator whose operands are the stream and the manipulator. The manipulator does not overload an operator *per se*.

The manipulator is indeed a function template. It is possible to overload operators so that one of the operands can be a function or a function template.  In the latter case, the overloaded operator is itself a function template.

In your last statement, the syntax `x << y` is transformed to the function call `operator<<(x, y);` and then the ordinary name lookup and overload resolution process resolves that call in the same way as any other function call.